# read files from a directory to a list

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I stuck in a practice. The practice asked me to load the images from a directory and save them to a list.
I have to complete the `load` method in the below code and not changing the `loadLibrary` method. I understood that I need to read the images to `allShreds` but I cannot figure out the right syntax. I also read the Java documentation but didn't find the examples useful.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class DeShredder {
    private List<Shred> allShreds = new ArrayList<Shred>();

    public void loadLibrary(){
        Path filePath = Path.of(UIFileChooser.open("Choose first shred in directory"));
        Path directory = filePath.getParent(); //subPath(0, filePath.getNameCount()-1);
        int count=1;
        while(Files.exists(directory.resolve(count+".png"))){ count++; }
        count = count-1;
        load(directory, count); 
        display();
    }

    /** 
     * Empties out all the current lists (the list of all shreds, 
     * the working strip, and the completed strips). 
     * Loads the library of shreds into the allShreds list. 
     * Parameters are the directory containing the shred images and the number of shreds. * Each new Shred needs the directory and the number/id of the shred. 
     */
    public void load(Path dir, int count) {
        allShreds.clear();
    }
}
```

The `Shred` class

```
public class Shred{

    public static final double SIZE = 40;
    private String filename;
    private int id;            // ID of the shred

    public Shred(Path dir, int id){
        filename = dir.resolve(id+".png").toString();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void draw(double left, double top){
        UI.drawImage(filename, left, top, SIZE, SIZE);
    }

    public void drawWithBorder(double left, double top){
        UI.drawImage(filename, left, top, SIZE, SIZE);
        UI.drawRect(left, top, SIZE, SIZE);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "ID:"+id;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `List` contains elements of type `Shred`. How does that relate to files?

Comment: Your requirement is not quite understandable from the given description. Can you please provide more details about what the `load` method does?

Also, can you please share the `Shred` class?

Comment: @UmFraWJ1bCBJc2xhbQ sorry, I've also added the Shred class

Comment: the hint says the `load` method should:     /**
     * Empties out all the current lists (the list of all shreds,
     *  the working strip, and the completed strips).
     * Loads the library of shreds into the allShreds list.
     * Parameters are the directory containing the shred images and the number of shreds.
     * Each new Shred needs the directory and the number/id of the shred.
     */

Comment: Well, as I can guess, in your `display` method, it calls the `draw` method from `Shred` class. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `allShreds` is an ArrayList containing `Shred` objects. The correct way for adding objects to Arraylist is calling the **add** method with appropriate object. In your case, you need to add `Shred` object to the ArrayList.

And, from your question, by `Loads the library of shreds into the allShreds list`, it is meant that, you only need to load the `Shred` into the list. Your `display` method will then do the rest of the work for drawing and displaying images.

So, basically you just have to loop through all the image id in the directory and create new Shred from that image id and directory. And, add each of the `Shred` to the list:

```
public void load(Path dir, int count) {
    allShreds.clear();

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        allShreds.add(new Shred(dir, i));
    }
}
```

About the query from your comment:

> Can you please also explain what does while in loadLibrary do ?

`while(Files.exists(directory.resolve(count+".png"))){ count++; }`

Here, it seems that, for the given test, in the given directory, always there need to have files in this sequence - `1.png`, `2.png`, `3.png`, etc.

Now, inside the while loop, at first value of count is 1 and `directory.resolve(count+".png")` returns the absolute path of `1.png` inside that directory. Then `Files.exists()` check if the path containing `1.png` really exists, which means if the file `1.png` really exists inside the given directory. If it exists, then the loop proceeds, the value of count becomes 2 and again it checks if `2.png` exists in given directory and so on until it finds a `[count].png` which doesn't exist in that directory.

Comment: thank you. Can you please also explain what does `while` in `loadLibrary` do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is little confusing. Your practice question reads: ".. I have to complete the load method in the below code and not changing the loadLibrary method".

- neither 'load' or 'loadeLibrary' is static. So assumption is the way you use `DeShredder` is following:

```
DeShreder deShreder = new DeShreder();
deShreder.loadLibrary(); //This would call `load`
```

- If you do not change `loadLibrary` method, actual choice of directory lies with `loadLibrary`. That means directory is already chosen. So why signature of load includes `dir`? What is the point of `count` parameter?
- Who decides how to write `Shred` class or is it already written?
- If you are to write it, should it not contain error handling because it may not be able to resolve the file?

There are few more questions but I think you get the point. I think the practice (question) is still not clear to you or it is pretty unfair.